# regex to match symbols between underscores

Tags: regex

I have strings like this:

```
(any symbol) _ (any symbol) _ (any symbol)
```

I need a short regex pattern to extract symbol sequences between `_`.

For example I have this string:

```
abc123_abc12345ABC_123abc
```

The regex should extract:

```
abc12345ABC
```

Answer (score 5):

This would do it:

> `^[^_]+_([^_]+)_[^_]+$`

The middle capture group would grab the middle string of characters.

Answer (score 2):

With *(any symbol)* do you really mean any symbol? Can it contain newlines? Can it contain underscores?

For now, I'll give this short regex:

```
_(.+)_
```

Answer (score 0):

`([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)`

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
^.*?_(.*?)_.*$
```

Answer (score -1):

And this

If you are using rebus package in R

```
library(rebus)
library(tidyverse)


separator <- '_' %R% one_or_more(ANY_CHAR, char_class = F) %R% '_'

 yx2 <- 'abc123_abc12345ABC_123abc'

 str_extract(yx2, separator) %>% str_remove_all("_")

[1] "abc12345ABC"
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not at all what the user is asking for! :)

Comment: Still not really what @zero is asking for. Generally speaking when someone asks for a regexp, they mean the standard format. While it's true there are minor differences in syntax depending on the specific language and regexp engine, most of them have a specific format in common. Instead, Rebus is just a completely different thing. I'm not saying your answer is wrong or bad, but rather: It's unlikely that it is what this user needs.